# OrderBy doesn't work on the first few items within an ng-repeat

Tags: arrays, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

For some reason, when I want to sort on name on an objectarray, the first 10 or so object seem to be random, after that the orderBy works perfectly.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you put an example of your data? or maybe a plnkr.co?

Comment: I actually found it, we are working with a huge data-set, but there are some spaces in front of the string!

Really stupid, should I close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there aren't any spaces in front of the string, when showing it on the HTML-template they might be invisible because of the way HTML get rendered.